# Implementing Exoplayer for Google VR SDK

Tags: android-studio, exoplayer2.x, gvr-android-sdk

I'm trying to make a VR app which can play a stereoscopic 360 degree video from a remote server. For that I use 360 degree sample app provided by the Google VR SDK for Android. It works fine with the default MediaPlayer of android.
Now I'm trying to replace the mediaPlayer with ExoPlayer and the app crash when I implemented the ExoPlayer.
What is the correct way of implementing ExoPlayer to this?